# AJAX - Show Loading Image Until Database Query Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've done a lot of searching for this question, but I can't find the particular answer.

I'm using the below code to perform a query.  The query takes from 1-6 seconds or more to process.  While waiting for the results I want the user to know that something is working:

```
<script language="javascript">
function ajaxRequest(){
var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
    //suppress error
   }
 }
}
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}
</script>


<script language="javascript">
function ajaxget(){
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mygetrequest.responseText
  }
 else{
  alert("An error has occured making the request")
   }
 }
}
var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
mygetrequest.open("GET", "findclosestcityresults.php?location="+namevalue, true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
}
</script>
```

I've tried to put code in along with a ajax loading image on the query php, but none of that will display until the content loads completely.

Thanks.

Edit:

Changed some of the code based on the link below, still can't get any traction...

```
<script language="javascript">
function ajaxget(){
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==0){
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="images/ajax_loader.gif" />';
 }
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==1){
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="images/ajax_loader.gif" />';
 }
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==2){
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="images/ajax_loader.gif" />';
 }
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==3){
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="images/ajax_loader.gif" />';
 }
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mygetrequest.responseText
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}


var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
mygetrequest.open("GET", "findclosestcityresults.php?location="+namevalue, true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
}
</script>
```

This is really my first time fooling around with javascript / ajax.  The first code example was something I found online.

Thanks again.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started - Read this. The answer to your question is in step 2.

Comment: just put the code for showing an image before calling ajax

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the heads up.  I edited the code above, but I guess I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
function ajaxRequest(){
var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
    try{
      return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
  }
  catch(e){
    //suppress error
  }
  }
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
return new XMLHttpRequest()
else
 return false
}
</script>


<script language="javascript">
function ajaxget(){
  var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
  mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
    if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mygetrequest.responseText
    }
    else{
      alert("An error has occured making the request")
    }
  }
}
var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
//new code here!
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<img src='path-to-ajax-loader-moving.gif' />";
mygetrequest.open("GET", "findclosestcityresults.php?location="+namevalue, true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code to display the loading image. I don't usually write the code for ajax call from scratch as what you did because a lot of js framework has support for this. The ajax call is called asynchronously so it shouldn't affect your loading image as long as you you don't display the image when you are in onreadystatechange, it should be fine. Just put it somewhere before or after you execute the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you tagged it as jQuery so:

```
$("#loading_animation").bind({
    ajaxStart: function() { $(this).show(); },
    ajaxStop: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```